# Не видит таблицу

Tags: python, ооп, sqlite, классы

Использую sqlite и python.
Все работает, если вызывать методы класса в самом файле класса.
Но если вызвать метод из главного файла приложения, пишет что не может найти таблицу.

Класс для работы с бд, где все работает если вызов делать из этого же файла.

```
def selectItems(self, nameSlt):
    return str(self.forTableAdd('slt', 'heroItem', str(nameSlt)))
```

Вызываем функцию forTableAdd

```
def forTableAdd(self, type, coll, name, collVal = False):
    if type == 'slt':
        self.connectDB()
        self.result = self.query('SELECT {} FROM `heroAdd` WHERE `heroName` = ?'.format(coll), (name,))
        self.data = self.result.fetchall()
        self.disconnect()
        return self.data
```

И в итоге после вызова selectItems('Имя_игрока'), получаем его инвентарь.

Но у меня так же есть класс для работы именно с сумкой игрока - items. Он наследуется от класс bd, в котором и дергаются записи из бд. И из файла items то же все работает. Когда я в файле с классом items вызываю метод getBag, он все возвращает как и должен.

Файл с классом Items

```
from myclass.language import Language
from myclass.db import db
import json

class Items(Language, db):

def __init__(self, lang, nameG):
    self.lang = lang
    self.nameGamer = nameG

def getBag(self):
    return self.selectItems(self.nameGamer)
```

Но когда я вызываю метод getBag в файле main.py, он возвращает ошибку:

> sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: heroAdd

Все файлы я импортировал, и судя по ошибке видно что доходит до запроса, но сам запрос возвращает ошибку.

Сначала думал что просто что то не передаётся, но потом просто в лоб решил использовать запись в файл передаваемых атрибутов. Методы все получают и передают.

Код в файле main.py

```
from myclass.locations import *
from myclass.items import *
from config import *

locat = Locations(landDefault)
language = Language(landDefault)
items = Items(landDefault, name)

startMess = [language.firstMess, language.secondMess, language.thirdMess]

positionHero = ''

i = 0

def query(data):
    global positionHero
    if data == 'help':
        return print(language.helpInfo)
    if data in locat.listLocation:
        positionHero = data
        return print(language.messMoving + positionHero)
    if data == 'bag':
        return print(items.getBag())
    if data == 'infoLocation':
        return getattr(locat, positionHero)()


print(query('bag'))
```

Comment: А таблица в базе есть?

Comment: да, я просто не понимаю почему запрос не проходит из файла main

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Могу написать возможные варианты:

1. Файл бд находится в другой директории
2. Имя таблицы не соответствует с запрашиваемой
3. Ошибка в функции передачи данных из таблицы
4. Нет такой таблицы

Скорее всего что-то из вышеперечисленного является ошибкой но, я не уверен.

Comment: 1) Ошибка возникает именно при запросе к таблице, уже после того как произошло подключение к БД. Она пишет что не находит именно таблицу. 2) Только что ещё раз проверил, все правильно. 3) Возврат после запроса - select, тут сложно что напутать) 4) Она есть

Comment: Ошибка настолько странная, и не типичная, что просто я хз что с эти делать. В файле items можно вытянуть данные, в файле db тоже. В main возникает такая фигня. Такой же экземпляр класса, такое же обращение. Ума не приложу в чем ошибка(

Comment: Проблема была в директории)